# Dúvida com belongsToMany laravel 7

Tags: laravel, relacionamento

Tenho um relacionamento N:N que esta me dando problema no retorno usando o `with()` segue o exemplo de minhas duas models com problema e a forma que faço a chamada da consulta.

Model product_type

```
public function makes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Make::class);
}
```

Model make

```
public function productTypes()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ProductType::class);
}
```

Minha table de relação tem os seguintes campos

```
make_product_type -> nome da tabela
make_id
product_type_id
```

Em minha controller estou tentando retornar todos os produtos com suas marcas desta forma

```
Make::with('productTypes')->get()
```

mas neste ponto é retornado o seguinte erro:

**Trying to get property 'make_id' of non-object**

Eu já tentei informar os campos do relacionamento na model mas também não deu certo.
A única forma que deu certo foi sobrescrevendo o método toArray() da model e forçando o relacionamento no retorno, o que para mim não é viável visto que só preciso retornar esse relação em um consulta que é executada.

```
public function toArray()
{
    return [
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
       'product_type' => $this->productTypes()->get()->toArray()
     ];
}
```

Se alguém puder me explicar o que estou fazendo errado e principalmente o por que esta errado agradeceria muito, pois já li várias vezes a documentação do Laravel e não obtive sucesso em entender qual o problema.
Obs. se houver sugestão de mudança na estrutura da tabela também não há problema pois estou iniciando um projeto e neste momento ainda posso mudar as coisas

Comment: Já tentou especificar a tabela da relation e os campos? Dessa forma: return `$this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ProductType::class, 'product_type_id', 'make_id');`

Comment: Tentei da seguinte forma `return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ProductType::class, 'make_product_type', 'make_id', 'product_type_id');` e o resultado é o mesmo erro que informei acima.

Answer (score 0):

Qual versão utiliza do laravel?
Fez uma tabela Pivo neste caso de N:N?

Tenta fazer assim:

**Model Make**

```
public function Products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product_type::class);
}
```

**Model Product_type**

```
public function makes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Make::class);
}
```

Tabela pivo?
(Em ordem alfabética)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('make_producttype', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('make_id');
        $table->bigInteger('producttype_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Na View seria assim para acessar.

```
        @foreach($make->productsas $pro)
             <p class="badge badge-success">{{$pro->name}}</p>
         @endforeach
```